# Viewing all email messages in a conversation and finding which have attachments

Tags: gmail

Every now and then, I wish to see all email messages in a conversation. I can globally do so using `Gear, Settings, Conversation View, Conversation view off`. How do I do so on a per conversation basis instead of globally?

How can I tell which one of these threads have attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn off conversation view for only one conversation. It's either all or none.

Individual messages have a "paperclip" icon at the top of the message (visible even when the conversation is collapsed) to indicate there is an attachment. Alternatively, you can search and use `has:attachment` as part of the search terms.

[image: conversation view, showing attachment icon]

Comment: Well, that is frustrating.  What about exporting an entire conversation to text, so I can view all threads at once without changing the global settings?

Comment: Sure, you could use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) to export your data, but that seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Yea, maybe so.  I will just toggle back and forth when needed.  Do you know how to tell which individual emails have documents attached?  Thanks

Comment: Looking at the entire conversation doesn't show the paperclip icons, however, searching certainly will.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531: I've added a screen shot.